# curl and resize remote image

Tags: php, curl, resize-image

I use this script to download and resize a remote image. In the resize part something goes wrong. What is it?

```
<?php
$img[]='http://i.indiafm.com/stills/celebrities/sada/thumb1.jpg';
$img[]='http://i.indiafm.com/stills/celebrities/sada/thumb5.jpg';
foreach($img as $i){
    save_image($i);
    if(getimagesize(basename($i))){
        echo '<h3 style="color: green;">Image ' . basename($i) . ' Downloaded OK</h3>';
    }else{
        echo '<h3 style="color: red;">Image ' . basename($i) . ' Download Failed</h3>';
    }
}

function save_image($img,$fullpath='basename'){
    if($fullpath=='basename'){
        $fullpath = basename($img);
    }
    $ch = curl_init ($img);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
    $rawdata=curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);




    // now you make an image out of it

    $im = imagecreatefromstring($rawdata);

    $x=300;
    $y=250;

    // then you create a second image, with the desired size
    // $x and $y are the desired dimensions
    $im2 = imagecreatetruecolor($x,$y);


    imagecopyresized($im2,$im,0,0,0,0,$x,$y,imagesx($im),imagesy($im));


    imagecopyresampled($im2,$im,0,0,0,0,$x,$y,imagesx($im),imagesy($im));

    // delete the original image to save resources
    imagedestroy($im);



    if(file_exists($fullpath)){
        unlink($fullpath);
    }
    $fp = fopen($fullpath,'x');
    fwrite($fp, $im2);
    fclose($fp);

    // remember to free resources
imagedestroy($im2);



}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I run it, PHP gives me the following error:

> Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 2 to be string, resource given ... on line 53

[`fwrite()`](http://php.net/fwrite) writes a string to a file. You want to use the GD function [`imagejpeg()`](http://php.net/imagejpeg) to save the GD resource to a file. It works for me when I change

```
$fp = fopen($fullpath,'x');
fwrite($fp, $im2);
fclose($fp);
```

to

```
imagejpeg($im2, $fullpath);
```

---

On an unrelated note, if all you're doing with cURL is grabbing the files, you can simply use [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/file_get_contents) instead of cURL, assuming PHP is configured to allow full URLs in fopen functions. (I believe it is by default.) See the Notes section on [the file_get_contents() manual page](http://php.net/file_get_contents) for more info. The function *is* binary-safe, so it works with images in addition to text files. To use it, I just replaced all six lines of the cURL functions with this line:

```
$rawdata = file_get_contents($img);
```

---

Update:
In response to your question below, you can specify a new file name for them in the array keys like so:

```
<?php
$img['img1.jpg']='http://i.indiafm.com/stills/celebrities/sada/thumb1.jpg';
$img['img2.jpg']='http://i.indiafm.com/stills/celebrities/sada/thumb5.jpg';
foreach($img as $newname => $i){
    save_image($i, $newname);
    if(getimagesize(basename($newname))){
```

Comment: Would it be possible to define a custom name for the image in: $img[]='http://i.indiafm.com/stills/celebrities/sada/thumb1.jpg';
ad pass it some way into the function?

Comment: @mark Sure. Code added in answer above, since there's not enough room here.