# Resize image from another server and show it in my website

Tags: php

I wanted to show image from another server, but a smaller image maintaining the aspect ratio and i will not be knowing the exact size of that image. Can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to grab the image from another server, for that you can use [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/file_get_contents).

Then you need some code to resize an image. Since you have the image content in a string rather than a local file, you can use [`imagecreatefromstring()`](http://php.net/imagecreatefromstring) try here:
[curl and resize remote image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853669/curl-and-resize-remote-image)

If you want to resize it down relative to the original then use `getimagesizefromstring()` to get the current size, then simply calculate the new size based on your chosen percentage.

```
$content = file_get_contents('http://site.com/image.jpg');

$originalSize = getimagesizefromstring($content);

$originalWidth = $originalSize[0];
$originalheight = $originalSize[1];

$newSize = 0.6; // 60% of the original size

$newWidth = $originalWidth * $newSize;
$newHeight = $originalHeight * $newSize;

// now you know what the resized width and height should be, you can go ahead and do the actual resizing
```

Comment: - But i dont want to fix size from my end.. It shld be relative to original image..